# Running Jar with Display from Server

Tags: centos, java

I have a Jar file which I would like to run on my server.  When I run using `java -jar MyJar.jar` I get this error:

```
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Dots.main(Dots.java:13)
```

Researching a bit, I found various solutions but none of them have solved my issue: `export DISPLAY=:0` and `xhost +` which, unfortunately returns

```
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
```

EDIT* Also tried `java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar MyJar.jar` but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Dots.main(Dots.java:13)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What exactly are you running this on?

Comment: Are you using `X11Forwarding`?

Comment: I am sshing into an CentOS server to try and run my jar.  I am not using `X11Forwarding`

Comment: That would be why it's not working.

Comment: Indeed.  I was able to figure how to solve that issue by using the ssh -X or -Y options.  Unfortunately, I have to wait 6 hours until I can answer my own question.  But if one of you wants to grab the the answer, feel free.  I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simply `ssh -Y <server>` or `ssh -X <server>` this will enable X11Forwarding which will allow you to run your program.  For me, however, the -X option times out X11Forwarding after a certain amount of time logged onto the server.  The -Y will keep x11Fowarding constant.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed what you've excluded so what about:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar MyJar.jar
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated with what I have tried to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to launch a X client like VNC on that display.  Did you already do that?

Comment: I have not.  How is that accomplished?